# How to kill pages that are cached with KeepAlive directive in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 3 entry point file `app.vue`, I defined a layout and a page inside it with vue's "keep-alive" directive to tell the router to cache pages. Like example below;

```
 <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage ref="page"  keepalive />
 </NuxtLayout>
```

And I have v-tabs in the layout.vue file, which acts like tabs in the Google Chrome, each of the tabs goes to different url therefore changes the nuxt-page using `<slot>`, such as ;

```
<v-window>
  <v-app-bar>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

    <v-card flat>
      <v-tabs v-model="menuStore.$state.currentTabIndex">
        <v-tab v-for="(tab, ti) in tabs" v-bind:key="ti" @click="changeCurrentTab(tab)" :to="tab.to">

          {{ tab.title }}

          <button v-if="!tab.isStatic" @click="menuStore.closeWindow(tab)">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </button>

        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
    </v-card>
  </v-app-bar>

  <v-card elevation="2">
    <v-card-text>


      <slot />  <!-- Slot that nuxt injects page components into -->


    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-window>
```

But, due to internal cache mechanism of Vue's keep-alive command, I'm unable to kill a page when a tab is removed from the opened tabs list (which is kept in a store).

I've tried to get the page instance from nuxt, and then forcibly call unmount() on the page component but couldn't accessed to the instance itself.

How can I forcibly remove the cached NuxtPage instance from router's cache ?